# How to fix unreliable hitboxes in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I've created a 2-player tank battle game, but the hitboxes of the tank seem a bit unreliable. Sometimes when a bullet is fired, it will hit the empty space next to a tank and count as a hit, but other times it will pass straight through the tank.

This is using Pygame for Python 3.6.3. This program is a modification of a program shown in "More Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner" by Jonathon Harbour (Chapter 12). I do not completely understand how the original creator defined the hitboxes, which is making it difficult to fix the issue. Since I'm not sure where the error is I've included the entire program. However, I believe either the Bullet class or def Draw in the Tank class may be the best places to look (I could very easily be wrong though).

```
# 2-Player Tank Battle Game

import sys, time, random, math, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from My_Library import *

class Bullet():
    def __init__(self, position):
        self.alive = True
        self.color = (250, 20, 20)
        self.position = Point(position.x, position.y)
        self.velocity = Point(0, 0)
        self.rect = Rect(0, 0, 4, 4)
        self.owner = ""

    def update(self, ticks):
        self.position.x -= self.velocity.x * 10.0
        self.position.y -= self.velocity.y * 10.0
        if self.position.x < 0 or self.position.x > 800 \
           or self.position.y < 0 or self.position.y > 600:
            self.alive = False
        self.rect = Rect(self.position.x, self.position.y, 4, 4)

    def draw(self, surface):
        pos = (int(self.position.x), int(self.position.y))
        pygame.draw.circle(surface, self.color, pos, 4, 0)

def fire_cannon(tank):
    position = Point(tank.turret.X, tank.turret.Y)
    bullet = Bullet(position)
    angle = tank.turret.rotation + 90
    bullet.velocity = angular_velocity(angle)
    bullets.append(bullet)
    play_sound(shoot_sound)
    return bullet

def player_fire_cannon():
    bullet = fire_cannon(player)
    bullet.owner = "player"
    bullet.color = (30, 250, 30)

def player2_fire_cannon():
    bullet = fire_cannon(player2)
    bullet.owner = "player2"
    bullet.color = (250, 30, 30)

class Tank(MySprite):
    def __init__(self, tank_file, turret_file):
        MySprite.__init__(self)
        self.load(tank_file, 50, 60, 4)
        self.speed = 0.0
        self.scratch = None
        self.float_pos = Point(0, 0)
        self.velocity = Point(0, 0)
        self.turret = MySprite()
        self.turret = MySprite()
        self.turret.load(turret_file, 32, 64, 4)
        self.fire_timer = 0

    def update(self,ticks):
        # update chassis
        MySprite.update(self, ticks, 100)
        self.rotation = wrap_angle(self.rotation)
        self.scratch = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, -self.rotation)
        angle = wrap_angle(self.rotation-90)
        self.velocity = angular_velocity(angle)
        self.float_pos.x += self.velocity.x * 2
        self.float_pos.y += self.velocity.y * 2

        # warp tank around screen edges (keep it simple)
        if self.float_pos.x < -50: self.float_pos.x = 800
        elif self.float_pos.x > 800: self.float_pos.x = -50
        if self.float_pos.y < -60: self.float_pos.y = 600
        elif self.float_pos.y > 600: self.float_pos.y = -60

        # transfer float position to integer position for drawing
        self.X = int(self.float_pos.x)
        self.Y = int(self.float_pos.y)

        # update turret
        self.turret.position = (self.X, self.Y)
        self.turret.last_frame = 0
        self.turret.update(ticks, 100)
        self.turret.rotation = wrap_angle(self.turret.rotation)
        angle = wrap_angle(self.turret.rotation)
        self.turret.scratch = pygame.transform.rotate(self.turret.image, -angle)

    def draw(self, surface):
        # draw the chassis
        width, height = self.scratch.get_size()
        center = Point(width/2, height/2)
        surface.blit(self.scratch, (self.X-center.x, self.Y-center.y))        
        # draw the turret
        width, height = self.turret.scratch.get_size()
        center = Point(width/2, height/2)
        surface.blit(self.turret.scratch, (self.turret.X-center.x,
                                           self.turret.Y-center.y))

    def __str__(self):
        return MySprite.__str__(self) + "," + str(self.velocity)

# this function initializes the game
def game_init():
    global screen, backbuffer, font, timer, player_group, player, \
           player2, bullets

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    backbuffer = pygame.Surface((800, 600))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Tank Battle Game")
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    # create player tank
    player = Tank("tank.png", "turret.png")
    player.float_pos = Point(400, 300)

    # create second player tank
    player2 = Tank("enemy_tank.png", "enemy_turret.png")
    player2.float_pos = Point(random.randint(50, 760), 50)

    # create bullets
    bullets = list()

# this function initializes the audio system
def audio_init():
    global shoot_sound, boom_sound

    # initialize the audio mixer
    pygame.mixer.init()

    # load sound files
    shoot_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("shoot.wav")
    boom_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("boom.wav")

# this function uses any available channel to play a sound clip
def play_sound(sound):
    channel = pygame.mixer.find_channel(True)
    channel.set_volume(0.5)
    channel.play(sound)

# main program begins
game_init()
audio_init()
game_over = False
player_score = 0
player2_score = 0
last_time = 0
action1 = False
action2 = False
action3 = False
action4 = False
action5 = False
action6 = False

# main loop
while True:
    timer.tick(30)
    ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    # event section
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                action1 = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                action2 = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                action3 = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                action4 = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                action5 = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                action6 = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                action1 = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                action2 = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                action3 = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                action4 = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                action5 = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                action6 = False

    if action1 == True:
        player.rotation -= 4.0
        player.turret.rotation -= 4.0
    if action2 == True:
        player.rotation += 4.0
        player.turret.rotation += 4.0
    if action3 == True:
        player2.rotation -= 4.0
        player2.turret.rotation -= 4.0
    if action4 == True:
        player2.rotation += 4.0
        player2.turret.rotation += 4.0
    if action5 == True:
        if ticks > player.fire_timer + 1000:
            player.fire_timer = ticks
            player_fire_cannon()
    if action6 == True:
        if ticks > player2.fire_timer + 1000:
            player2.fire_timer = ticks
            player2_fire_cannon()


    # update section
    if not game_over:
        # move tank
        player.update(ticks)

        # update player two
        player2.update(ticks)

        # update bullets
        for bullet in bullets:
                bullet.update(ticks)
                if bullet.owner == "player":
                    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(bullet, player2):
                        player_score += 1
                        bullet.alive = False
                        play_sound(boom_sound)
                elif bullet.owner == "player2":
                    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(bullet, player):
                        player2_score += 1
                        bullet.alive = False
                        play_sound(boom_sound)

    # drawing section
    backbuffer.fill((100, 100, 20))

    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(backbuffer)

    player.draw(backbuffer)

    player2.draw(backbuffer)

    screen.blit(backbuffer, (0, 0))

    if not game_over:
        print_text(font, 0, 0, "PLAYER 1: " + str(player_score))
        print_text(font, 650, 0, "PLAYER 2: " + str(player2_score))
    else:
        print_text(font, 0, 0, "GAME OVER")

    pygame.display.update()

    # remove expired bullets
    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.alive == False:
            bullets.remove(bullet)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing here, since there's a couple of extra import files needed to run the code.  But looking at the `Bullet` class, it seems to define it's collision rectangle from `(x,y)` to `(x+4, y+4)`.  However, when the bullet is draw to the screen, it uses `pygame.draw.circle()`  which draws *centred* on `(x,y)`, so the on-screen bullet is a little out-of-position with respect to the collision rectangle.  But that said, it's only 2 pixels out.

```
def update(self, ticks):
    self.position.x -= self.velocity.x * 10.0
    self.position.y -= self.velocity.y * 10.0
    if self.position.x < 0 or self.position.x > 800 \
       or self.position.y < 0 or self.position.y > 600:
        self.alive = False
    self.rect = Rect(self.position.x, self.position.y, 4, 4)

def draw(self, surface):
    pos = (int(self.position.x), int(self.position.y))
    pygame.draw.circle(surface, self.color, pos, 4, 0)
```

With respect to the bullet passing though the tank - the code only checks collisions at each point in the update path, and seems to step 10 pixels (times `velocity`) distance each update.  So the bullet may only exist just-before the tank, but has moved to just-after at the time of the next update.

A way to fix this would be to calculate every pixel-point along the path the bullet takes between two points, and see if any of those co-ordinates happen to overlap the tank.  An algorithm like the [Mid-Point Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) would be a simple way to enumerate the points.  Most examples of this algorithm in code only handle the simple case, and do not work in-general for lines of all gradients.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I can add the My_Library file that I imported if it would help you find a solution.